# JAX RS apps in Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jax-rs, cloud-foundry

I have a set of rest services built using JAX-JS running on tomcat servers. I am planning to migrate them to cloud foundry.  Is it mandatory for me to convert these into spring boot apps to deploy on cloud foundry or are there any alternate approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to convert your applications to Spring Boot. Cloudfoundry's Java buildpack [supports any Servlet 2 or Servlet 3-based application](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/container-tomcat.md).

Comment: Thanks Andy , I guess spring boot provides its own embedded tomcat container. If I deploy a servlet application without any embedded container , will cloud foundry automatically create an instance of tomcat ? If so would I have to specify the container in my manifest file ?

Comment: I believe it'll use Tomcat by default. You can control the version in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks Andy , I will try it out!